# Duplicate symbols only for iOS simulator build

Tags: c++, ios, c, xcode, linker-errors

I'm having a strange issue when compiling an open source library. When compiling for the device, Xcode compiles it just fine and deploys it no problem. However, when I compile for the simulator, I get duplicate symbol errors during the linking phase.

I've checked a few of these out, and it seems these symbols were all implemented in the .hh file as opposed to the .m file. Obviously this is bad code structure, and the errors make sense. However, what doesn't make sense is why there are *no* errors for the device build.

Each of these .hh files contains #pragma once at the top of the file. My initial thought was that this wasn't working as expected, but upon removal I get compile-time errors for both device and simulator builds stating I've redefined these symbols. Hmm, so I then tried replacing #pragma once with

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_DEFINE
#define EXAMPLE_DEFINE

// code

#end if
```

But this yields identical results to the #pragma once.

Due to the sheer number of code changes that would be required, it isn't feasible for me to go through and fix every error manually, especially since I'll want to be able to update the codebase easily. So is there any reason this is not failing for the device, and how I could make simulator builds perform the same way?

EDIT: I've also tested using #import instead of #include, but it too yields the same results

EDIT 2: After more testing, I've found that if I define a Preprocessor macro in the target's build settings, the code inside the #ifndef never gets called, as is expected. For whatever reason, it looks like defining the new definition in the .hh file isn't being carried over into the next compilation of the file.

Also, as requested, here's an excerpt from the build log

```
duplicate symbol __ZZN12DelegateFuncIFvR16DualTextMenuItemRKN5Input5EventEEEC1IZN25MultiChoiceSelectMenuItem4initEPPKciiibSB_P12ResourceFaceEUlS1_S5_E_EERKT_PNSt3__19enable_ifIXntsr3std11is_functionISG_EE5valueEvE4typeEENKS8_ISF_EUlRKNS7_7StorageES1_S5_E_cvPFvSR_S1_S5_EEv in:
    /Users/riley.testut/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GBA4iOS-dqkflotukruucqbxjyslhtfuekse/Build/Intermediates/GBA4iOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GBA4iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/Main-FB93852047D42061.o
    /Users/riley.testut/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GBA4iOS-dqkflotukruucqbxjyslhtfuekse/Build/Intermediates/GBA4iOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GBA4iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/OptionView.o
duplicate symbol __ZZN12DelegateFuncIFbiRKN5Input5EventEEEC1IZN15MultiChoiceView4initER19MultiChoiceMenuItemb9_2DOriginEUliS3_E_EERKT_PNSt3__19enable_ifIXntsr3std11is_functionISC_EE5valueEvE4typeEENKS6_ISB_EUlRKNS5_7StorageEiS3_E_cvPFbSN_iS3_EEv in:
    /Users/riley.testut/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GBA4iOS-dqkflotukruucqbxjyslhtfuekse/Build/Intermediates/GBA4iOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GBA4iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/Main-FB93852047D42061.o
    /Users/riley.testut/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GBA4iOS-dqkflotukruucqbxjyslhtfuekse/Build/Intermediates/GBA4iOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GBA4iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/OptionView.o
duplicate symbol __ZZN12DelegateFuncIFvR12TextMenuItemRKN5Input5EventEEEC1IN14YesNoAlertView2noMUlS1_S5_E_EEERKT_PNSt3__19enable_ifIXntsr3std11is_functionISB_EE5valueEvE4typeEENKS8_ISA_EUlRKNS7_7StorageES1_S5_E_cvPFvSM_S1_S5_EEv in:
    /Users/riley.testut/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GBA4iOS-dqkflotukruucqbxjyslhtfuekse/Build/Intermediates/GBA4iOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GBA4iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/ButtonConfigView.o
    /Users/riley.testut/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GBA4iOS-dqkflotukruucqbxjyslhtfuekse/Build/Intermediates/GBA4iOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GBA4iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/MenuView.o
ld: 16 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and here's one of the offending files (AlertView.hh):

```
#pragma once

#include <gui/View.hh>
#include <gui/MenuItem/MenuItem.hh>
#include <util/gui/BaseMenuView.hh>
#include <util/rectangle2.h>
#include <util/DelegateFunc.hh>

class AlertView : public View
{
public:
    constexpr AlertView() { }
    Rect2<GC> labelFrame;
    Gfx::Text text;
    BaseMenuView menu;
    Rect2<int> rect;

    Rect2<int> &viewRect() { return rect; }

    void init(const char *label, MenuItem **menuItem, bool highlightFirst);
    void deinit() override;
    void place() override;
    void inputEvent(const Input::Event &e) override;
    void draw(Gfx::FrameTimeBase frameTime) override;
};

class YesNoAlertView : public AlertView
{
public:
    YesNoAlertView() { }
    typedef DelegateFunc<void (const Input::Event &e)> InputDelegate;

    MenuItem *menuItem[2] = {nullptr};

    // Optional delegates
    InputDelegate &onYes() { return onYesD; }
    InputDelegate &onNo() { return onNoD; }

    void init(const char *label, bool highlightFirst, const char *choice1 = nullptr, const char *choice2 = nullptr)
    {
        yes.init(choice1 ? choice1 : "Yes"); menuItem[0] = &yes;
        no.init(choice2 ? choice2 : "No"); menuItem[1] = &no;
        assert(!onYesD);
        assert(!onNoD);
        AlertView::init(label, menuItem, highlightFirst);
    }

    void deinit() override
    {
        logMsg("deinit alert");
        AlertView::deinit();
        onYesD = {};
        onNoD = {};
    }

    InputDelegate onYesD;
    InputDelegate onNoD;
private:
    TextMenuItem yes
    {
        [this](TextMenuItem &, const Input::Event &e)
        {
            auto callback = onYesD;
            removeModalView();
            if(callback) callback(e);
        }
    };
    TextMenuItem no
    {
        [this](TextMenuItem &, const Input::Event &e)
        {
            auto callback = onNoD;
            removeModalView();
            if(callback) callback(e);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Please post the build log showing the dupes.

Comment: Ok I've updated the question with build log and offending file

Answer (score 0):

It shows you have tried the header guards but my suggestion is once you check for following 
link.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RedundantIncludeGuards

The update shows it is linker error for symbols and this is for the library you are using.

Comment: Nothing here seems to have any effect

Comment: Check for the class name you have defined is present anywhere else.